# Can R packages add code snippets to users' snippet files?

Tags: r, package

There are several code snippets that are invaluable to my workflow and play nicely with functions in my custom R package. Can I include these code snippets in my R package so that they are added to users' code snippets (with permissions of course) when they install my package?

Rmd snippet example that creates a sql chunk:

````
snippet sql
    ```{sql, connection = conn, output.var = "${1:df}"}
    ${2}
    ```
````

Comment: The "Saving and Sharing Snippets" section at the bottom of https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets may be helpful for you. You could probably have a function in your package that uses `cat(..., append = TRUE)` to put your snippets to the end of those files mentioned in the linked article. However, I don't know if you could do it on installation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

One way to achieve what you want (that works for my package) is:

1. Store the packages snippet definitions in two text files somewhere in the packages `inst/` directory. It's important that the snippets follow *exactly* the formatting rules (e.g. tabs at the start of the lines, not spaces). I have one file for R code snippets and one for markdown.
2. Define a function that reads these files and copies their content into RStudios *user* snippets files. These files are generated at the first attempt to edit the snippets (Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Edit Snippets) (I think RStudio uses an other, not user exposed file before one tries to edit, not sure though). On ubuntu the RStudio files are called 'r.snippets' and 'markdown.snippets' and are in '~/.R/snippets/'. I also check if the snipped definition already exists, and double check the tabs at the start of the lines before using `cat(..., append=TRUE)` to add the packages snippet definitions.
3. I first used an elaborate `.onLoad` function with configs and all but now I just export a `addPackageSnippets` function ;)

## Edit

Some code:

Part that checks for already existing snippet definitons:
I just read the rstudio file and extract the lines starting with 'snippet'. I do the same for the packages snipptes definition file and use `setdiff` (one might want to also use `trimws` on the lists, just in case there is some trailing white-space)

```
# load package snippets definitions
#
pckgSnippetsFileContent <- readLines(pckgSnippetsFilesPath)

# Extract names of package snippets
#
pckgSnippetsFileDefinitions <- pckgSnippetsFileContent[grepl("^snippet (.*)", pckgSnippetsFileContent)]

# Extract 'names' of already existing snitppets
#
rstudioSnippetsFileContent <- readLines(rstudioSnippetsFilePath)
rstudioSnippetDefinitions <- rstudioSnippetsFileContent[grepl("^snippet (.*)", rstudioSnippetsFileContent)]

# find definitions appearing in packageSnippets but not in rstudioSnippets
# if no snippets are missing go to next file
#
snippetsToCopy <- setdiff(pckgSnippetsFileDefinitions, rstudioSnippetDefinitions)
```

For context here is the whole 'addPackageSnippets' function. The function is using only the base package, except `getOS` which returns one of 'linux', 'windows' or 'mac' (i.e. a wrapper around `Sys.info()`

```
#' @title Export snippets
#'
#' @description \code{addPackageSnippets} copies all (missing) snippet definitions
#'   in 'inst/rstudio/Rsnippets.txt' and 'Rmdsnippets.txt' to the RStudios user snippet location.
#'
#' @return boolean invisible(FALSE) if nothing was added, invisible(TRUE) if snipped definitions were added
#' @export
#'
#' @examples \dontrun{addPackageSnippets()}
addPackageSnippets <- function() {

  added <- FALSE

  # if not on RStudio or RStudioServer exit
  #
  if (!nzchar(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY"))) {
    return(NULL)
  }

  # Name of files containing snippet code to copy
  #
  pckgSnippetsFiles <- c("Rsnippets.txt", "Rmdsnippets.txt")

  # Name of files to copy into. Order has to be the same
  # as in 'pckgSnippetsFiles'
  #
  rstudioSnippetsFiles <- c("r.snippets", "markdown.snippets")

  # Path to directory for RStudios user files depends on OS
  #
  if (getOS() == "linux") {
    rstudioSnippetsPathBase <- "~/.R/snippets"
  } else if (getOS() == "windows") {
    rstudioSnippetsPathBase <- file.path(path.expand('~'), ".R", "snippets")
  } else {
    warning(paste0("goSnippets() is only implemented on linux and windows"))
    return(NULL)
  }

  # Read each file in pckgSnippetsFiles and add its contents
  #
  for (i in seq_along(pckgSnippetsFiles)) {

    # Try to get template, if template is not found skip it
    #
    pckgSnippetsFilesPath <- system.file("rstudio", pckgSnippetsFiles[i], package = "myFunc")
    if (pckgSnippetsFilesPath == "") {
      next()
    }

    # load package snippets definitions
    #
    pckgSnippetsFileContent <- readLines(pckgSnippetsFilesPath)

    # Extract names of package snippets
    #
    pckgSnippetsFileDefinitions <- pckgSnippetsFileContent[grepl("^snippet (.*)", pckgSnippetsFileContent)]


    # Construct path for destination file
    #
    rstudioSnippetsFilePath <- file.path(rstudioSnippetsPathBase, rstudioSnippetsFiles[i])

    # If targeted RStudios user file does not exist, raise error (otherwise we would 'remove')
    # the default snippets from the 'user file'
    #
    if (!file.exists(rstudioSnippetsFilePath)) {
      stop(paste0( "'", rstudioSnippetsFilePath, "' does not exist yet\n.",
                   "Use RStudio -> Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Edit Snippets\n",
                   "To initalize user defined snippets file by adding dummy snippet\n"))
    }

    # Extract 'names' of already existing snitppets
    #
    rstudioSnippetsFileContent <- readLines(rstudioSnippetsFilePath)
    rstudioSnippetDefinitions <- rstudioSnippetsFileContent[grepl("^snippet (.*)", rstudioSnippetsFileContent)]

    # replace two spaces with tab, ONLY at beginning of string
    #
    pckgSnippetsFileContentSanitized <- gsub("(?:^ {2})|\\G {2}|\\G\t", "\t", pckgSnippetsFileContent, perl = TRUE)

    # find defintions appearing in packageSnippets but not in rstudioSnippets
    # if no snippets are missing go to next file
    #
    snippetsToCopy <- setdiff(trimws(pckgSnippetsFileDefinitions), trimws(rstudioSnippetDefinitions))
    snippetsNotToCopy <- intersect(trimws(pckgSnippetsFileDefinitions), trimws(rstudioSnippetDefinitions))
    if (length(snippetsToCopy) == 0) {
      # cat(paste0("(\nFollowing snippets will NOT be added because there is already a snippet with that name: ",
      #            paste0(snippetsNotToCopy, collapse=", ") ,")"))
      next()
    }

    # Inform user about changes, ask to confirm action
    #
    if (interactive()) {
      cat(paste0("You are about to add the following ", length(snippetsToCopy),
                 " snippets to '", rstudioSnippetsFilePath, "':\n",
                 paste0(paste0("-", snippetsToCopy), collapse="\n")))
      if (length(snippetsNotToCopy) > 0) {
        cat(paste0("\n(The following snippets will NOT be added because there is already a snippet with that name:\n",
                   paste0(snippetsNotToCopy, collapse=", ") ,")"))
      }
      answer <- readline(prompt="Do you want to procedd (y/n): ")
      if (substr(answer, 1, 1) == "n") {
        next()
      }
    }

    # Create list of line numbers where snippet definitons start
    # This list is used to determine the end of each definition block
    #
    allPckgSnippetDefinitonStarts <- grep("^snippet .*", pckgSnippetsFileContentSanitized)

    for (s in snippetsToCopy) {
      startLine <- grep(paste0("^", s, ".*"), pckgSnippetsFileContentSanitized)

      # Find last line of snippet definition:
      # First find start of next defintion and return
      # previous line number or lastline if already in last definiton
      #
      endLine <- allPckgSnippetDefinitonStarts[allPckgSnippetDefinitonStarts > startLine][1] -1
      if (is.na(endLine)) {
        endLine <- length(pckgSnippetsFileContentSanitized)
      }

      snippetText <- paste0(pckgSnippetsFileContentSanitized[startLine:endLine], collapse = "\n")

      # Make sure there is at least one empty line between entries
      #
      if (tail(readLines(rstudioSnippetsFilePath), n=1) != "") {
        snippetText <- paste0("\n", snippetText)
      }

      # Append snippet block, print message
      #
      cat(paste0(snippetText, "\n"), file = rstudioSnippetsFilePath, append = TRUE)
      cat(paste0("* Added '", s, "' to '", rstudioSnippetsFilePath, "'\n"))
      added <- TRUE
    }
  }

  if (added) {
    cat("Restart RStudio to use new snippets")
  }

  return(invisible(added))

}
```

Comment: can you share code showing how you check for existing snippets to avoid duplicates?

Comment: @Joe I added the part that checks for existing snippets as well as the whole function. Feel free to ask here if you need more help

Comment: great work! never thought of doing that! Thanks for the question and the answer!

Comment: Really great answer. Small suggestion: I used `warn=FALSE` inside `readLines()` so that I don't get incomplete last line warnings

Comment: I really like this answer, though I assume it will need to be defined and exported from  every package that uses it. Would be a great pull request to add to this to devtools (probably?) with a package name argument or url to github repo.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who comes across this thread, and to add to Dario's great answer: from RStudio v1.3, the filepaths have changes. So in his function, the section for setting `rstudioSnippetsPathBase` would need to change into something like the following

```
if (rstudioapi::versionInfo()$version < "1.3") {
    rstudioSnippetsPathBase <- file.path(path.expand('~'),".R", "snippets")
  } else {
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
      rstudioSnippetsPathBase <- file.path(Sys.getenv("APPDATA"), "RStudio", "snippets")
    } else {
      rstudioSnippetsPathBase <- file.path(path.expand('~'), ".config/rstudio", "snippets")
    }
  }
```